# Why does MS-SSTP use huge Content-Length for streaming rather than Transfer-Encoding: chunked?

Tags: http, vpn

[4.1 HTTP Layer Establishment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247364.aspx)

It looks very uncool in terms of semantics. The maximum of Content-Length is not defined in HTTP specification and in the case where the entire size of the content is unavailable, it's preferable to use Chunk Transfer Encoding.

Are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question conjecturally, since no one responds to this for long time. I infer that if we used Transfer-Encoding: chunked, we have to cut up a payload of connection into pieces of fixed-size. In that case, we have to watch for a chance to make a chunk. Nobody knows when to cut a chunk. So it is a good idea to set a excessively huge integer to Content-Length.